# Equivalent condition for indicator function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality

We have the following two conditions:

$C1.$ $l(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$,
$C2.$ $l(x) \geq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $a+b^Tx \leq 0.$

Here $l(x) = \begin{bmatrix} x^T 1 \end{bmatrix} M \begin{bmatrix} x \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$

We have to show that $C2.$ is equivalent to
$C3.$: there exists $\tau \geq 0$ such that for every $x$,  $l(x) \geq 1-2\tau (a+b^Tx). $

Here is what I have tried:

$C1.$ is equivalent to the fact that $M \succcurlyeq 0$. 
If $C3.$ holds then,  under $a+b^Tx \leq 0$, $l(x) \geq 1-2\tau (a+b^Tx) \geq 1.$ Hence, $C2.$ holds.

The following exact statement from [paper](http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eelghaoui/Pubs/wcVaR_OR2003.pdf)
concludes that $C2.$ gives $C3.$

With $C1.$ in force, an application of the classical strong
duality result for convex programs under the Slater assumption
shows that the
above condition is sufficient, provided there exists an $x_0$ such
that  $a+b^Tx_0 <0.$

I am having trouble here. I tried writing a convex problem
$$
\min_{x} l(x)-1 
\\
\text{s.t.} a+b^Tx \leq 0.  
$$
So we get its Lagrange function as $L(x,\tau) = l(x)-1 + \tau (a+b^Tx) $. A KKT point will satisfy $C3.$, but I am unable to show it for every $x$. Moreover I am not using $C1. $ but the statement takes it into account.

This question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719806/equivalent-condition-for-indicator-function).

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
\begin{array}{lrl}
p^\star = &\min& l(x)-1 \\
&\text{s.t.}& a+b^Tx \leq 0.
\end{array}
$$
Assumption C1 tells us that this is a convex optimization problem, and existence of a Slater point, $x_0$, satisfying $a + b^T x_0 < 0$, tells that this convex optimization problem satisfies strong duality. That is,
$$
\max_{\tau \geq 0} \min_x L(x,\tau) = p^\star.
$$

where $L(x,\tau) = l(x)-1 + \tau (a+b^Tx)$ is the Lagrange function. By assumption C2, telling us that $p^\star \geq 0$, we thus have that the optimal dual multiplier, $\tau^\star \geq 0$, satisfies
$$
\min_x L(x,\tau^\star) \geq 0
$$
and thus we conclude $L(x,\tau^\star) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which is equivalent to C3.